# Track and display how many times users have clicked a button on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, server

Im trying to figure out a way to track how many times users have clicked a button on my website, so simply adding a value of 1 to the total number everytime it is clicked.

Im just not sure how I would store and access this number.
New to html and javascript so please keep it simple,
Thank you!

Comment: Did you do anything, a html tag? script supporting the page? Anything?

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(this).click(function(){
             /** Perform Operations Here To Save Click Count **/             
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a HTML5 data attribute to store the count as an attribute of the button rather than just a global variable and increment the count / update the data-count on each click.

Another client side solution would be to use local / session storage to store the count.

Note that if you want a server side solution and have access to it - you will need to use php or similar and save the data into a database.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#clicker').click(function(){
    var count = parseInt($(this).attr('data-count')) + 1;
    $('#clickedNum').text('The button was clicked ' + count + ' times');
    $('#clicker').attr('data-count', count);
   });
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button name="button" id="clicker" data-count='0'>Click Me</button>
<p id="clickedNum"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is:

```
<div id="showCount"></div>
<input type="button" id="btnClick" value="Click me" onclick="CountFun();/>
```

Now the function to count is:

```
var cnt=0;
function CountFun(){
 cnt=parseInt(cnt)+parseInt(1);
 var divData=document.getElementById("showCount");
 divData.innerHTML="Number of Clicks: ("+cnt +")";

}
```

Comment: This doesn't store it server side though right? I want to be able to count every user who clicks the button and display the combined total.

Comment: This doesnt store on serverside. Number of clicks will display the number of times the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen the click of corresponding button and store it.

```
<button name="button" >Click Me</button>

var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
     var numOfClick = 0;
     ele[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
      numOfClick = numOfClick + 1;
    });
```